# Cursor Usage in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-cursor

Here is my code;

```
CREATE TABLE Splitter
(
     Id INT
    ,Vals VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO Splitter VALUES
(1,'A,B,C'),
(2,'D,E,F')

DECLARE @Id INT
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE(Id int, Vals varchar(10))

DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR 

    select Id, Vals from splitter

OPEN MyCursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @Id, @Str 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

     insert into @Tbl
     select @Id, substring(@Str,charindex(',',@Str)-1,1)
     set @Str=substring(@Str,charindex(',',@Str)+1,len(@Str))

FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @Id,@Str 

END 

CLOSE MyCursor  
DEALLOCATE MyCursor
```

I want to list values row by row as below;

```
1-A
1-A
1-A
2-D
2-E
2-F
```

Whats wrong for my code? I just want to know how cursor does work..Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is `1-A` `1-A` `1-A` a typo?

Comment: It is just result set. '-' is not important sign.

Comment: Using a cursor is the first problem. Cursors are the *slowest* way to do anything in SQL, except for some very advanced cases. What are you trying to do? SQL is a set-based language. Anything you want to do can be done with queries and it will be faster than a cursor.

Comment: @aprkturk Are you trying to *split* a string perhaps? There are dozens of duplicates that are 10-100 times faster than a cursor. SQL Server 2016 introduced `STRING_SPLIT` anyway.

Comment: @aprkturk I don't think Andrew's asking about the hyphen, but rather you have 3 `1-A`s; did you instead want `1-A`, `1-B`, `1-C`?

Comment: @aprkturk another option is to *avoid* comma-separated values completely. Table-valued parameters can be used to pass multiple values to a SQL query parameter

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, CURSORS are part of the language (in all DBMSs I know) and hence are there to be used, wisely, but used. I do agree with you that, for the posted question, it would be obvious to make a simple SELECT, but I'm guessing the that OP is drastically simplifying things. Are you OP?

Comment: @FDavidov that's why the advice is *don't use them unless you know what you are doing, because they are the most common reason for scalability disasters*. The only case where they can run faster is batch processing of 100s of thousands of rows. The code posted here is a string splitter. There are several [well known](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-stringst) techniques and cursors [aren't one of them](https://sqlblog.org/2010/07/07/splitting-a-list-of-integers-another-roundup). There's a reason they are called the `Row By Agonizing Row` techniques

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, please do not misunderstand my words. I fully agree with you (as I wrote) in that the use of CURSORS must be well justified (and hence the word _wisely_). Obviously, for the posted example it makes no sense (and even makes things more difficult than a simple `select`). I was only saying that (my guess) is that the OP's needs are more complex than the example.

Answer (score 4):

Your question started good with proper sample data and code, but ended bad with "Whats wrong for my code?" - Your current code returns:

```
1    a
2    d
```

This is because you are setting the `@str` variable inside the loop, but then overwrite it with the cursor.

Splitting strings in SQL Server should be done using built in `string_split` if you are working on 2016 or higher, and prior to that version by Adam Machanic's CLR function. If you are working on a version lower than 2016 and can't use CLR for some reason, you should probably use an XML splitter, as shown in Aaron Bertrand's [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings), or Jeff Moden's [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

In SQL, a cursor is usually the wrong tool to do anything. SQL works best with a set based approach, not with a RBAR approach (which is all that a cursor can do).

Basically, a cursor just takes the resultset of it's select statement and spit it out Row By Agonizing Row with `fetch next`
This usually means terrible performance compared to the same operation done in a set based approach.
This does not mean that you should never use cursors, but it is what I would refer to as a last resort, and only when you absolutely have no other choice.

Comment: "This is because you are setting the @str variable inside the loop" thank u!, I corrected my query.

Comment: @aprkturk the problem is using cursors in the first place. Zohar already posted links to *fast, well tested answers*. Those answers can be converted to table-valued functions *very* easily making it a lot easier to use them in queries

Answer (score 3):

If using SQL Server 2016, just use STRING_SPLIT:

```
select Id, cs.Value 
from Splitter
cross apply STRING_SPLIT (Vals, ',') cs
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try and avoid cursors where possible, they are a basic loop that leads to Row-by-Row solutions that can be very slow on large SQL datasets. Cursors also reserve space in the Buffer (memory) and can steal resources from other processes. If you have to loop you should use a WHILE construct.

SQL offers other SET based solutions that can replace a CURSOR solution.

Your goal may more efficiently be achieved with a Recursive CTE.

Here's an example of a Recursive CTE that can replace the need for your cursor:

```
CREATE TABLE #Splitter
(
     Id INT
    ,Vals VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #Splitter VALUES
(1,'A,B,C'),
(2,'D,E,F')   

;WITH cte AS
    (
    --Anchor point, the first Value from each ID
    SELECT
        Id
        ,LEFT(Vals,CHARINDEX(',',Vals)-1) AS Val
        ,RIGHT(Vals,LEN(Vals)-CHARINDEX(',',Vals)) AS Remainder
    FROM #Splitter
    WHERE 
        Vals IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(',',Vals)>0
    UNION ALL
    --Central Recursion for each value
    SELECT
        Id,LEFT(Remainder,CHARINDEX(',',Remainder)-1)
        ,RIGHT(Remainder,LEN(Remainder)-CHARINDEX(',',Remainder))
    FROM cte
    WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(',',Remainder)>0
    UNION ALL
    --Error prevention, handling the end of the string
    SELECT
        Id,Remainder,null
        FROM cte
        WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(',',Remainder)=0
    )
    SELECT ID,VAL FROM cte
```

If your [Vals] column is always in a set format then you could use CROSS APPLY with VALUES for a more efficient solution.

```
SELECT
    ID
    ,v.Val
FROM
    #Splitter S
        CROSS APPLY (VALUES (left(S.Vals,1)),(SUBSTRING(Vals,3,1)),(RIGHT(Vals,1))) v(Val)
```